# How to make a div scale to the max height available?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, height

I have a div filled with a an image contained within another div spanning the top and bellow it a p, I would like it so that the image portion('child') spans to the max-height available without pushing the text out of the div, is this possible?

example code:

Html:

```
<div className='parent'>
  <div className='child'>
    <img/>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sass:

```
.parent{
 position: absolute;
        width: 85%;
        height: 85%;
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 20%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 7px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #7510f7;

  .child{
           display: flex;
           width: 100%;
           background: #141c3a;
           height: 40vh;
           overflow: hidden;

    img{
           width: auto;
           height: auto;
           max-width: 100%;
           max-height: 100%;
           object-fit: cover;
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           margin: auto;
    }
   
  }

  p{
      text-align: left;
      width: 95%;
      margin: auto;
      font-size: 0.9rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you produce a mock up of what you are trying to achieve? You added flex to the child, so why does the height matter? flex, without specifying flex-directions, means the img and the p will be next to each other?

Comment: Sure I can make a code sandbox in five minutes if you don't mind waiting, the display flex was so I could centre the image within the using margin auto. Instead of using demo code, I can build my actual project within a sandbox if that'll help?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-sunset-jqjst?file=/src/App.js here's the sandbox requested, I hope this helps you understand:)

Comment: a running code snippet could help more in understanding the part where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently as your `child` div has `display: flex;`, the `img` and `p` elements will be side-by side.

Adding `flex-direction: column;` to the `child` element might be what you want, see the below snippet (added border colours to tell elements apart)

```css
.parent {
  width: 85%;
  height: 85%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #7510f7;
  border: red 1px solid;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: #141c3a;
  height: 40vh;
  border: orange 1px solid;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: auto;
  border: green 1px solid;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
  border: blue 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <img/>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Update

Given your sandbox, here are the styles you need to add to get it how you want:

```
  .Cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .carousel-root{
      flex:1;
    }
    .carousel, .slider-wrapper, .slider {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .slide{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there not what I was looking for really but thanks for the response, The content is aligned perfectly but I want the top image portion to fill the maximum amount of space possible without pushing the text element out of the div. here's an image of my project layout https://imgur.com/a/yaVe7v3

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-sunset-jqjst?file=/src/App.js here is a sandbox basically showing off an uglier version of the code for my project, I would like the image portions height to expand depending on the screen length to fit the top portion removing the space under th text how can I do this?

Comment: Thanks again for your edit but adding the code you posted It doesn't seem to change the function of the card? could you post it in the sandbox and send the link across would be greatly apreciated

Comment: my mistake works perfectly can't thank you enough mate!

Comment: One last question would it be possible to have the dive containing the image be 100% of the size of carousel-root?

Comment: It would be easiest if you could jsut remove that div, or give it a class or id selector, currently it is just a plain div. Alternatively you can select it with CSS as the first-child of the parent class.

Comment: Thanks, it already has a className but setting it too 100% sets the height too 100% of the card not 100% of the carousel, is there any way I can private message you? I need it to set a background colour when the images don't fit the carousel

Comment: Is there a way to pm on here I just realised your code doesn't quite work when you remove the set height value for .image-iframeContainer or set it to 100%(should be 100% of the carousel root?), it looks like it works but if you stretch the aspect ratio it pushes the text outside the div anyway? thanks for your help so far btw!